# How i can translate UI object position to 3d world position in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to translate a position of UI item to the 3d space how i can do this in unity and C#
i tried to do this but it doesn't work :

```
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(UI.Canvas.transform.position);
```

My canvas is in screen space overlay mode.

Comment: This question is about [tag:C#], not [tag:unityscript]. Anyway, what is the render mode of the canvas?

Comment: @Ruzihm the render mode is "Screen space overlay"

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? If any below were helpful, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) to give the answerer some reputation points and help others browsing the search panel that there is a helpful answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/overlay-canvas-and-world-space-coordinates.291108/#post-3253600) by **karma0413** on the Unity forums:

> I found this after a couple years because i was having a problem with
> the conversion between world coordinates back to screen coordinate
> position..
>
> WorldToScreenPoint is slightly off!
>
> When canvas scaler mode is set to: stretch to screen size
>
> The problem is that the canvas screen point is not actually the same
> screen size as the current resolution... the canvas screen size is
> more like, the best optimized view screen resolution... under the
> stretch parameters you can see the variables for Reference
> Resolution.. this is the resolution of the canvas.
>
> A better explanation of CANVAS SCALING is by using my most recent
> problem...
>
> Quick Description of my problem: I was using the Canvas to display a
> sprite ( a healthbar) which floats over all the characters. The
> problem however, was when i tried to obtain the WorldToScreenPoint it
> kept giving a result that was slightly off.... for example: the
> healthbar looked a little okay when the character was immediately in
> front of the camera... but as the character walks to the edge of the
> camera's fulstrum, the screens x,y placement becomes more and more
> incorrect.
>
> Days and days of research and trying different combinations finally
> showed me that maybe there is a scaling issue which pointed me to look
> at **Canvas / Canvas Scaler / scaling mode: scale with screen**
>
> Originally, this worked wonderfully when i had only 1 character and
> his healthbar stayed stuck to the top of the screen like old classic
> double dragon games. BUT when i made the decision to have many
> characters and they all need "floating healthbars", i didnt come back
> to re-evaluate whether this option needed to change.
>
> **Setting the canvas Scaler to: keep constant pixel size** , fixes the problem and i now have the correct WORLDtoSCREENpoint that i needed!
> And now the healthbar floats beautifully above the characters...
>
> BUT WAIT, ANOTHER PROBLEM! Now, if the screen resolution is small...
> the Ui sprite is obsurdly large..... and if the screen resolution is
> high definition then Ui sprite is way too small!
>
> QUESTION: So how do i use the "scale with screen size" mode, but yet
> also still get back a correct WorldToScreenPoint?
>
> ANSWER: you must take into consideration the overal scaling of the
> canvas when it is stretched to fit (whatever current resolution that
> you are using)
>
> INSTEAD OF:
>
> ```
> myPositionOnScreen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (myOwner);
> myRect.anchoredPosition = myPositionOnScreen
> ```
>
> YOU CALCULATE THE OVERALL SCALE FACTOR LIKE THIS:
>
> ```
> RectTransform myRect = GetComponent<RectTransform>(); Vector2
> myPositionOnScreen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (myOwner);
>       Canvas copyOfMainCanvas = GameObject.Find ("Canvas").GetComponent <Canvas>(); float scaleFactor =
> copyOfMainCanvas.scaleFactor
>       Vector2 finalPosition = new Vector2 (myPositionOnScreen.x / scaleFactor , myPositionOnScreen.y / scaleFactor);
> myRect.anchoredPosition = finalPosition;
> ```
>
> If this helped anyone please log in to give me a thumbs up....

Answer (score 1):

```
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(UI.Canvas.transform.position);
```

That will give you the 3D world position of the UI Canvas (game object). You were on the right track, that method converts a 2D screen space point to a world space position. But you entered a world space position.

Instead, what you want is the screen space position of the canvas item and convert it to world space. A bit of back and forth I guess.

```
Vector3 uiElementPosition = CanvasCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(CurrentUIElementWorldPosition);
```

Feels redundant so there might be a better way but once you have that, you can apply it to the game cam.

```
Vector3 coolNewWorldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(uiElementPosition);
```

Comment: He doesn't have CanvasCamera, his canvas is in Overlay mode